# Why doesn't firebase javascript authentication work with ie11?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented google authentication on a web page using firebase sdk.

It works fine on chrome, firefox and edge, but on ie11 I get a google authentication page but the authenticated user information is always null.

I think it's supported in ie 11.
firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk

I added the polyfill by cdn and executed it but it doesn't work. User information is still null.
unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.0.1/minified.js

Why doesn't it only work with ie11?

```
*function signInGoogle() {
    if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    } else {
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    }
}

function initApp() {
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
        var user = result.user;
        console.log(user);   // always null 
        if (user) {
            document.getElementById('createForm').submit();
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        var email = error.email;
        var credential = error.credential;
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        if (errorCode === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
            alert('You have already signed up with a different auth provider for that email.');
        } else {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });

}*
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No console error was displayed

Comment: I'm guessing this is a dead end.  IE11 does not support promises.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk   
I think it's supported in ie 11.

Comment: As a side note, ie support stopped on 1/12/16. If you need a reason to justify not supporting the browser. The ultimate bug fix.

Comment: According to the docs you linked to, IE11 requires the [ES Stable polyfill](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#suggested-polyfills)

Comment: https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.0.1/minified.js 

I added the polyfill by cdn and executed it but it doesn't work.  User information is still null

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce the SDK size, Firebase no longer ship the Polyfils that are required for some older browsers. This was one of the changes in the 6.x release.

Please take a look at https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk how to manually [enable Polyfills](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#polyfills) as required.